# Xamarin. Capturing the log from the app

Tags: logging, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid for the current app. we are having some issues with web services and sometimes it results in crashes and sometimes it just hangs without crashing in iOS and Android.

My question is, is there a way we can log each and every event that user does and capture them and send it across through any API's so we can exactly find out where the exact issue is so we can fix it in our next release.

Comment: services like HockeyApp and Crashlytics (and others) help you do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can track user actions using HockeyApp like this:

```
HockeyApp.MetricsManager.TrackEvent(
"Custom Event",
 new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Page", "LoginPage" } },
 new Dictionary<string, double> { { "Action", "LoginBtn clicked" } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate HockeyApp for logging bugs in your app(on both platforms).

Android:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/hockeyappandroid

Ios:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/hockeyappios

Comment: I am using hockey app for crashes. I need to monitor each and every steps user does like which page he went and which button he clicked and capture and back those back.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you Log4Net, its very easy, and have many documentation

[Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)